# Maximum Entropy in Scipy 0.18.1

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I tried using the conditional model of Maximum Entropy in Scipy but it says

```
module 'scipy' has no attribute 'maxentropy'
```

I have version 0.18.1, is there another alternative library I can use to create a Maximum Entropy model for my Machine Learning task?

EDIT:

Here's the code by the way

```
from __future__ import division    
import nltk
import re
import scipy

with open("Bigrams.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
f.close()
content = [x.strip() for x in content] 
maxEntModel = scipy.maxentropy.conditionalmodel(content,100,len(content))
```

Comment: You where not very complete if you got this message at `import` or when trying to run a function from this library. Please be more complete. In any case from the SciPy documentation: **"Warning This module is deprecated in scipy 0.10, and will be removed in 0.11. Do not use this module in your new code. For questions about this deprecation, please ask on the scipy-dev mailing list."**

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks. However, I still edited the post for clarification